# How to get the parent id of the parent when we click on the child check box

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

i am having an kendo treeview with checkbox template.

my html code

```
<div id="treeview-left" style=" height: 375px; position: absolute;top: 30px;"></div>
```

I have defined the treeview like:

```
var treeview1 = $('#treeview-left').kendoTreeView({
            select: onSelect,
            checkboxTemplate: kendo.template($("#treeview-checkbox-template").html()),            
            dragAndDrop: true,
            dataSource: parent, 
            dataTextField: ["parentName", "childName"]
        }).data("kendoTreeView");
```

And the checkbox template is defined like:

```
<script id="treeview-checkbox-template" type="text/kendo-ui-template">
            <input type="checkbox" />
</script>
```

And the datasource will be

```
var parent = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: "/Projects/leftdisplay"
                }
            },
            schema: {
                model: {
                    id: "parentid",
                    hasChildren: "childName",
                    children: child
                }
            }
        });
```

now the child of the parent will be like:

```
   var child = {
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: function (options) {
                        return kendo.format("/projects/modulesleftdisplay?parentid=" + options.parentid + "&roleid=" + rolevalue + "&projectid=" + projectid + "");
                    }
                }
            },
            schema: {
                model: {
                    id: "childid",
                    hasChildren: function () {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        };
```

Now when i am clicking on the child checkbox i want to get the parent id of the selected child. How can i get that.

I have written code like

```
$("#treeview-left [type=checkbox]").live('change', function (e) {      
    var chkBox = $(this)
    var parentid = chkBox.parent();
    var date = $('#treeview-left').data('kendoTreeView').dataItem(parent_id);
    var parid = date.id;
    var childid = $('#treeview-left').data('kendoTreeView').dataItem(parentid);
});
```

but the parid is not getting. How can i get the parent id of the selected child. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @Naidu, inspecting one basic questions: When you compute `date`, what is `treeview`? Is it `treeview` or `treeview-left`?.

Comment: @OnaBai I have used treeview-left also but still no success

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// Find all the checkboxes:
var checkboxes = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('#yourFormsID input[type=checkbox]'));

checkboxes.forEach(function(checkbox) {                //<== loop through checkboxes
    checkbox.addEventListener('change', function() {   //<== When clicked:
        console.log(this.parentNode.id);               //<== Log the id of the checkbox's parentNode in the console.
    }, false);
});
```

[Here's a demo](http://jsbin.com/aheqev/1/edit). Be sure to open the console.

Comment: where should i use that in check box change event and what is element and parentNode

Comment: I am not using forms. I am using kendo ui treeview. the example is not working for me

Comment: @Naidu What browser are you using? Did you open the console to see what happens when you click on the checkboxes?

Comment: yah it is getting undefined

Comment: @Naidu I can't help you unless you're more descriptive. "It's not working" is not descriptive, and neither is "it is getting undefined". What is getting undefined?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```
   var parentId = $(this).parent().closest(parent element).attr('id')
```

Example:

```
 var parentId  = $(this).parent().closest('li').attr('id')
```

instead of

```
 var chkBox = $(this)

 var parentid = chkBox.parent();
```

to get the parent id.

Comment: what is the parent element

Comment: what should be the parent element in the first example. I am getting undefined if i am using the second example

Comment: what you are expecting there

Comment: It will be an integer number which will be assigned to each parent

Comment: I have given the code in my question. Initially in the parent datasource the parent elements are assigned and then the childs will be assigned for each parent